# android spinner equivalent in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

googled a lot but could not find any spinner plugin for phonegap android. The plugin should be similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: or something similar to actionsheet in ios

Answer (score 0):

you may check Fries, it has native-like spinners http://jaunesarmiento.me/fries/#spinners